# How can I print over multiple lists in a loop while being mapped to each other?

Tags: python, list, loops, printing

By using the function I made, I want to print the records of all the employees using only one loop.

```
     Record = [["ali", "Mazen", "Fida", "Nader", "Majd"], ["Tutor", "IT", "Manager", "PR", "Clerk"]]
    def Netsal(salary):
        bonus=0
        if salary<2000:
            bonus = 300
        elif salary>=4000:
            bonus = 100
        else:
            bonus = 200
        return salary + bonus
    Sal=[2200,1600,4000,2000,1400]
    holder=[]
    for base_salary in Sal:
        total_salary=Netsal(base_salary)
        holder.append(total_salary)
    for total_salary in Netsal(base_salary):
        print(Record, total_salary)
```

I'm kinda lost when it comes to printing because I need to have an output like:

```
Mazen - IT : 1900
```

So the two sublists in the record need to also be mapped to the new salary list with the bonus.

Plus I need to loop over the lists and print all the values in the format I showed above.

Comment: What are you printng Ali with IT? Isn't `Ali` a `Tutor`?

Comment: my bad, i haven't slept in a while sry

Answer (score 1):

Before you run the last loop to print, you have three lists:

- `Record[0]` is a list containing names
- `Record[1]` is a list containing departments
- `holder` is a list containing net salaries.

`zip()` can take any number of iterables (a list is an iterable), and return tuples containing one element from each iterable. The `for` statement can unpack this tuple into the same number of variables.

```
for person, department, salary in zip(Record[0], Record[1], holder):
    print(f"{person} - {department} : {salary}")
```

Your code has an unnecessary loop though. You could remove the loop that populates `holder` and incorporate that logic in the `zip` loop I showed above like so, using the `Sal` list in `zip()`:

```
for person, department, base_salary in zip(Record[0], Record[1], Sal):
    net_salary = Netsal(base_salary)
    print(f"{person} - {department} : {net_salary}")
```

In the `print()` statements, I use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for string interpolation

Comment: that's what i did, thank you very much. it worked!